# WCF: Identical config file on server and client side?

Tags: c#, wcf-binding

My WCF service hang randomly. when I try to debug using **Microsoft Service Trace Viewer** I found out I was getting

> The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error
>   processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the
>   remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket
>   timeout was '00:01:00'.

Therefore I change the "receiveTimeout" in the Net pipe binding section (***server side***) like this.

> *Server side*

```
  <netNamedPipeBinding>
    <binding name="myPipeBinding"
             receiveTimeout="24:0:0">
    </binding>
  </netNamedPipeBinding>
```

And then I try to update the config file of the client using the Visual Studio 2013 "Update Service Reference". It give me the new App.config in the ***client side*** like this.

```
 <bindings>
  <netNamedPipeBinding>
    <binding name="NamedPipedService" />
  </netNamedPipeBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="net.pipe://localhost/Server" binding="netNamedPipeBinding"
    bindingConfiguration="NamedPipedService" contract="WCFService.IServer"
    name="NamedPipedService">
    <identity>
      <userPrincipalName value="Server\MyComputer" />
    </identity>
  </endpoint>
</client>
```

I thought everything work but my service crash again with the same error. So I thought "receiveTimeout" section of the "netNamedPipeBinding" should also be added in the client's App.config file. My question is

1. Is the error I am getting due to default timeout value of Net pipe binding?
2. Should I set the receiveTimeout value (server side) ?
3. Do I also need to change the App.config file in the client side for the changes to take effect? Since updating by Visual Studio 2013 does not add the receiveTimeout section.